# How to pass a function as a parameter in admin class

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, sonata-admin

Good morning, I have a little problem using sonata admin bundle, let's suppose that I have a function which returns a String, I want to pass the result of this function into as a parameter in the datagrid : something like :

```
protected $datagridValues = array (
'email' => array ('type1' => 2, 'value' => function()), // type 2 : >
'_page' => 1, // Display the first page (default = 1)
'_sort_by' => 'id' 
);
```

Any one knows a way to do this ? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `getFilterParameters()` method to change your `$datagridValues`:

```
public function getFilterParameters()
{
    $this->datagridValues = array_merge(array(
            'email' => array ('type1' => 2, 'value' => function()),
        ), $this->datagridValues);

    return parent::getFilterParameters();
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Michael, I did this but what should I pass to 'value' in my admin class to make the filter works ?

Comment: You asked how to set `$datagridValues['value']` to a value returned by function. I answered you. How can I know what do you want to pass to this value?

Comment: ok I did that and in the function() implementation I returned a String but the filter is not applied

Comment: Sorry, I had bad code. I updated my answer. Now it must have right filter.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `function()` in

```
'email' => array ('type1' => 2, 'value' => function())
```

Pass a correct var and it will work.

```
'email' => array ('type1' => 2, 'value' => 'myValue')
```

**EDIT**

To pass a function in arguments (named a **callback function**), you have to pass the callback name in argument, and use the `call_user_func` to run it then:

```
function mycallback(){
    // do things
}

protected $datagridValues = array (
    'email' => array ('type1' => 2, 'value' => 'mycallback')
    '_page' => 1,
    '_sort_by' => 'id' 
);
```

Then you can do in your script :

```
call_user_func($datagridValues['email']['value']);
```

Comment: Thank you @Rémi it works but I need to execute the function first to store the return value in the variable, where can I  execute it ?

Comment: Ah no it does not work in fact It interpret 'myValue' as a String and not as variable

Comment: Please note my edits if you want to pass a function in arguments.

Comment: I noticed this, but where could I add this line ? in the configureDatagridFilters() function ?

Comment: Ah ok it seems good but I got an exeption : Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'mycallback' not found or invalid function name

Comment: Did you defined it ?

Answer (score -1):

within array you cant call a function..
you can do this way.

```
$var = function_name();

protected $datagridValues = array (
'email' => array ('type1' => 2, 'value' => $var), // type 2 : >
'_page' => 1, // Display the first page (default = 1)
'_sort_by' => 'id' 
);
```

Comment: the syntax is 'value' => 'var' without the '$' @Aniket, but thank you anyway bro

Comment: You have syntax error here. PHP doesn't support for calling functions at field definition.

Comment: here function() means name of the function which you are calling.